# How to handle python signal exception?

Tags: python, try-catch, signals, alarm

```
def signal_handler(signum, frame):
    raise Exception("Timeout")

def my_function():
        signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, signal_handler)
        signal.alarm(1)
        try:
            call_long_function()
        except Exception as e: # Doesn't work
            print("Hello, Timeout!")
            break
        signal.alarm(0)
```

How to correctly handle signal exception? Also I tried to handle Timeout exception, it doesn't work too.

It just prints "Error: Timeout" to the console and after it program will be closed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which version of python are you using?

Comment: @m170897017, Python 2.7.9

Answer (score 2):

You're probably better off subclassing Exception into your own Exception class:

```
class TimeOutException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, message, errors):
        super(TimeOutException, self).__init__(message)
        self.errors = errors
```

Then you can do:

```
def signal_handler(signum, frame):
    raise TimeOutException("Timeout!")
```

Then, in the other function:

```
try:
   call_long_function():
except TimeOutException:
   print "Got a timeout!"
   break
```

Comment: I tried it, result is "Error: Timeout". Except block doesn't work (finnaly block works)

Comment: Ohh, if I pass in try block some code like `while(True): pass` it works perfectly! But if I pass a long function where I using `pipes` it doesn't work. Do you have an idea?

Comment: sorry; there was a typo. the "except" starting the except block should not be capitalized! I corrected it.

Comment: The finally block has a different purpose. `finally` indicates a block that is _always_ executed; regardless whether an exception occurred or not.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to create a specific exception class for the timeout exception so you can differentiate between it and other exceptions.

```
class TimeoutException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass
```

Define an alarm signal in your function, and set a timer.
Then wrap your time limited code with a try/except.
In this example i used two cases - one for the timeout exception class - one for any other sort of exception assuming the code can fail for more than one reason.

```
def my_function():
    signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, signal_handler)
    signal.alarm(1) #  Time Limit
    try:
        time.sleep(120) #  Simulation of code exceeding time limit
    except TimeoutException:
        print "Time out"
    except:
        print "Some other exception"

def signal_handler(signum, frame):
    raise TimeoutException()
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Thanks, i added comments explaining the script.

Answer (score -5):

try using the following snippet:

```
try:
//CODE
except Exception,e:
//handle the exception.
```

The whole point is not to use the expression `Exception as e`

Comment: Thanks, but I got same result.